# shp files in .net and convert to kml

Tags: .net, kml, shapefile

I am working on application with maps in .net.

I want to read shp files in .net and convert them to kml.

I dont want a tool, I need dll or code so that I can do it at run time.

Can you help me on this?

Regards,

Rahul M

Comment: Why can you not use a tool, when you're having to convert them to another file format (rather than reading the data "as-is")? How far have you got writing something to read/write yourself? (as the file formats are open)

Comment: I cannot use a tool because i want to parse it at runtime and generate map

Comment: Have you actually tried to read the files yourself?

Comment: not really, Is conversion that easy? and how do i proceed in .net c#

Comment: I'd be surprised if it took more than half a day - all the file format information is linked from the relevant Wikipedia article.

Comment: i want to convert from shp to kml using c#. can you help me on same

Answer (score 0):

Use open source projects like QGIS, DotSpatial etc.
YoU can use compiled libraries.